# Define Docker commands aliases

Tags: docker, alias, docker-compose

I several of my projects I am using `docker` and `docker-compose`.

It's great, but now many command I am using are very long, like

```
docker run --rm -it -v $(pwd):/app -u $(id -u):$(id -g) php:7.1 php vendor/bin/phpunit
```

I would like to use just something like

```
docker phpunit
```

providing details in `docker-compose` or some other configuration file.

Is there a way to define aliases of these commands on a **per project** basis?

I don't want to use global aliases since such commands can vary for every project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply add a bash script `docker.sh` to each one of your projects:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
docker run --rm -it -v $(pwd):/app -u $(id -u):$(id -g) php:7.1 php vendor/bin/phpunit
```

and run it with `./docker.sh`. This is a easy way to customize it considering each particularity and have the command under your version control.

Comment: Don't forget to `chmod +x ./docker.sh`

Comment: Yep! Don't forget! :D